Wiring switch from light with no power at light
how to wire a new switch and light from an existing light that has the power source at the switch. I am having trouble finding a power source for one led ceiling light. It was originally installed off a 3-way switch.

Can you please clarify the issue, are you trying to add a light to an existing one? Are you trying to combine lights and delete a switch? Are you adding a whole separate switch and light?

I am trying to add a new switch and light.

There is a 3 way circuit but the power is at the other side of the bathroom at the other switch. There is a light from the kitchen below but it is not the power instead it is from the switch. There isnt any power to pull from that I can find. The tub had lights and it ran off the 3 way, so the only way the tub light worked is if the 3 way switch was on correctly.

If it's what I'm thinking, you might have it rough. If you can send a picture of the inside of both boxes, I might be able to help you better, but these will have to suffice for now.
Here's what I got from what you've told me.

You've got two Switch Boxes
The switch leg side of you're 3-way has only the travelers and switch leg  in it (no power)
You're trying to add a new switch next to your switch leg side(I assume for a vanity)

If all that is true, I might have a solution for you.
Solution 1: Getting Power Into The Box
This involves running a power jumper between the two boxes. You must run the appropriate Romex between the two and make them up correctly. Take your "hot" wire from the common side of the 3-way and wire nut/pigtail it with the Romex black. Tie neutrals and grounds together. Then, tie neutrals and grounds together in the switch leg box. Run the new switch leg and hot on a single-pole switch.
Solution 2: Use Pico Switches
This involves running a switch leg from your power box into your light. Then, you get a Pico switch and run it—all in the same box. Then, you pair the other side of the Pico and place that on your wall, which acts as a wireless 3-way switch. Although this method may be messy, I'm assuming you'll have to cut in a two-gang box on your power side.
Solution 3: Random BS I made up While thinking about this (may or may not work :) )
I had fun with this one; in theory, it will work. I've never actually tried this before, so I can't be 100% certain. You'll still use pico switches, but you won't have to do any cutting. You'll have to disconnect your commons and travelers from the switches for this. On the power side of your 3-way, you will tie your travelers into the power, so you'll have two hots in the switch leg box. Then, as you would normally, you will add the new switch leg for the light and your single pole switch and connect the two. This is your new light, and it is done. Then, you will add a Pico smart switch in the same box and hook it up like a single pole with a hot in and a switch leg out. This switch is now done. Then you can pair the other part of the pico and put that where your power side three-way was.
